# How to run get_dummies() function on multiple columns for the same category type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have features DataFrame that (let us say) looks like this:

| Symptom A | Symptom B |
| --- | --- |
| Itching | Rash |
| Rash | Itching |

When I run the get_dummies function on this dataframe, it will create four columns named `'Symptom_A_Itching', 'Symptom_A_Rash', 'Symptom_B_Rash', 'Symptom_B_Itching'`. I don't want to treat the two values separately as it is being done with this function.

Is there any way to perform one hot encoding for this dataframe, where the values of both these columns won't be treated separately.

Basically, I want to get a DataFrame with columns `'Symptom_Itching', 'Symptom_Rash'`.

I tried using the columns and prefix arguments in the get_dummies function, but that did not produce any results. I also tried setting all the Symptom column names to just `'Symptom'` instead of `'Symptom_A', 'Symptom_B'`, but that also didn't work.

This is the code I have:

```
data_frame: DataFrame = read_csv('dataset.csv')
features: DataFrame = data_frame.iloc[:, 1:]
features.fillna('')
x: DataFrame = get_dummies(features)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted your code as well. Otherwise this question may be flagged for incomplete information / `asking for code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html):

```
out = (df
   .stack().str.get_dummies()
   .groupby(level=0).max()
 )
```

Or using a trick to get all output columns with the same name and [`groupby.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html) on `axis=1`:

```
out = (pd.get_dummies(df.rename(columns=lambda x: ''), prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).max()
       )
```

Output:

```
   Itching  Rash
0        1     1
1        1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to drop columns. From documentation:

**pandas.DataFrame.drop**

> Drop specified labels from rows or columns.
>
> Remove rows or columns by specifying label names and corresponding
> axis, or by specifying directly index or column names. When using a
> multi-index, labels on different levels can be removed by specifying
> the level.

For the example given, you can try (you need to *adapt* this approach for your csv parsing):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        'SymptomA': ['Itching', 'Rash'],
        'SymptomB': ['Rash', 'Itching']
    })
df_onehot = pd.get_dummies(df['SymptomA'])
df = df.drop('SymptomA', axis=1)
df = df.drop('SymptomB', axis=1)
df = df.join(df_onehot)
print(df)

# Output:

#    Itching   Rash
# 0     True  False
# 1    False   True
```

Comment: That's incorrect and the shown output wouldn't be generated by the shown code. Is this answer AI generated?

Comment: @mozway did you try and execute my code before making that statement?

Comment: @R__i_i to be honest no I hadn't, but now I have and my statement was correct. `get_dummies` doesn't yield booleans. Plus `df = df.drop('SymptomA', axis=1) ; df = df.drop('SymptomB', axis=1)` is non-sense, if you drop and overwrite there is no more columns. And you never get the dummies on SymptomB. Many mistakes that make it looks AI generated...

Comment: @mozway it does for me: https://imgur.com/HxQglKl

Comment: Then it's not this code... Which pandas version did you use?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing what I can to avoid AI answers on SO as they are polluting the site. I don't believe I insulted you, I just asked questions to understand the non-reproducibility of your code.

Comment: FWIW, I went throught your other answers and I already have upvoted answers if yours. I'm only questioning this one because the logic is flawed.

Comment: You haven't answered on the pandas version, I'm genuinely trying to understand why the output can't be reproduced.

Comment: Sorry missed your question. Here you go: https://imgur.com/KcKpgOo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254812/discussion-between-mozway-and-r-i).

Comment: I see, it's due to the new API, that now returns a bool by default. My apologies regarding this concern. I stand by my other comments though.